# Get data from rows from a table made with ngfor

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

Im working on an angular application. I have a table that dynamically populates based on what stores a user select. The table displays the data with dropdown menus with the current value of the data in it. I want the user to be able to modify the data and then select which rows are going to be updated based on a check box.

current html code

```
    <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Select</th>
        <th scope="col">Store ID</th>
        <th scope="col">MIR Opt-In</th>
        <th scope="col">SMS Opt-in</th>
        <th scope="col">Push Opt-in</th>
        <th scope="col">Loyalty Opt-in</th>
        <th scope="col">MIR Program</th>
        <th scope="col">Missed Quote time promo</th>
        <th scope="col">Minutes Over Promo</th>
        <th scope="col">Minutes Over</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let store of stores">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="selectupdate"></td>
        <td>{{store.STORE}}</td>
        <td><select [(ngModel)]="store.MIR_OPT_IN">
            <option value="true">true</option>
            <option value="false">false</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><select [(ngModel)]="store.SMS_OPTIN">
            <option value="true">true</option>
            <option value="false">false</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><select [(ngModel)]="store.PUSH_OPTIN">
            <option value="true">true</option>
            <option value="false">false</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><select [(ngModel)]="store.LOYALTY_OPTIN">
            <option value="true">true</option>
            <option value="false">false</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><select [(ngModel)]="store.MIR_PROGRAM">
            <option value="MISSED_QUOTE_TIME">Missed quote</option>
            <option value="MINUTES_OVER">Minutes Over</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><select [(ngModel)]="store.MISSED_QUOTE_TIME_PROMO">
            <option value="FREE_LARGE_PIZZA">Large Pizza</option>
            <option value="FREE_MEDIUM_PIZZA">Medium 2 toping pizza</option>
            <option value="FREE_BREAD_STICKS">Bread Sticks</option>
            <option value="TWENTY_PER_OFF">20% Off</option>
        </select></td>
        <td><select [(ngModel)]="store.MINUTES_OVER_PROMO">
            <option value="FREE_LARGE_PIZZA">Large Pizza</option>
            <option value="FREE_MEDIUM_PIZZA">Medium 2 toping pizza</option>
            <option value="FREE_BREAD_STICKS">Bread Sticks</option>
            <option value="TWENTY_PER_OFF">20% Off</option>
        </select></td>
        <td>{{store.MINUTES_OVER}}</td>

    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Current look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E954p.png)

The stores array is populated by a http request based a user's input earlier in the page.
So I want the user to be able to change the dropdown selections then hit the update button to update the values but I don't know how to get the data from the table. is there some way to use ngModel is this kind of functionality even possible?

Comment: Can I see the error and your .ts file?

Comment: its not an error I just don't know how to get the data from the table. Im not even sure where to start.

Comment: Due to the fact that you use `ngModel`, the `stores` array is going to be mutated when the user changes the selection, so when you need the values (on a click handler for example), you have them in `this.stores`.